# C code missing getchar() command in while loop first time round

Tags: c, getchar

I am writing a menu system in C, the code works correctly  but for some reason the first first time the while loop is entered for the menu it skips the getchar() command and runs through the while loop again, but the second time round it works? 
Any ideas as to why it does this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structs.h"

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char fileName[25], line[200], userInput = ' ';
    int len;

    while (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Enter The File To Load In: \n");
        scanf("%s", fileName); // Ask User For File Name
        fp = fopen(fileName, "r"); // Open File To Read
        if (fp == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error While Loading File\n");
        }
    }

    while (userInput != 'g') 
    {   
        printf("        |User System|\n");
        printf("A) Save Current Data To A File\n");
        printf("B) Enter Details\n");
        printf("C) View Details\n");
        printf("D) Amend Details\n");
        printf("E) Search by Award Title\n");
        printf("F) Search by Surname\n");
        printf("G) Shut Down\n");
        userInput = getchar();

        if (userInput == 'c') 
        {
            fgets(line, 200, fp);
            len = strlen(line);
            printf("%s", line);
            userInput = getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first `getchar` consumes the new line character? prefer to read by lines.

Comment: Did you press enter ? use debugger to see what it read the first time .

Answer (score 0):

After 'scanf'  use

```
getchar();
```

to consume extra newline. As 'scanf' can not discard newline, first iteration of 'getchar();' take the newline.

So you shold place `getchar()` after `scanf` as to consume extra newline('\n')

```
scanf("%s", fileName);
getchar();
```

It's better to use 'fgets' instead of `scanf` as file name may have space.
You can use 'fgets()' as

```
fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
fileName[strlen(fileName)-1] = 0; //Replace newline with '\0' character
```

Comment: You should explain **why**, not just **how**.

Comment: Thankyou very much! i forgot i needed to flush the buffer!

Comment: What I'm saying: what if the next character is not a newline?

Comment: @AaronNebbs: Do not feel tempted to use `fflush(stdin)`!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That case 'fgets` is the choice.

Comment: fair warning... `fgets` "Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character."